# Get status from checkbox with PHP and Bootstrap CSS

Tags: javascript, php, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to create a contact form using PHP and bootstraps CSS. Now I got most of the things working, however I need to get the status from multiple checkboxes and post the "labels" from the checked boxes only in the mail. I know this doesn't work as simple like I say and I've seen some online pages about this using javascript or Ajax etc. But I can't get it working, currently this is my page:

--UPDATE--

Thank you for the answer once again but still getting a 500 error page:
http://prntscr.com/6u21xy

```html
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) 
{

$message=
'Full Name: '.$_POST['fullname'].'<br />
Subject: '.$_POST['subject'].'<br />
Phone: '.$_POST['phone'].'<br />

foreach($_POST['check_list'] as $check) {
$message .= .$check . '<br>';       
}


Email: '.$_POST['emailid'].'<br />
Comments: '.$_POST['comments'].'
';
    require "PHPMailer-master/class.phpmailer.php"; //include phpmailer class
      
    // Instantiate Class  
    $mail = new PHPMailer();  
      
    // Set up SMTP  
    $mail->IsSMTP();                // Sets up a SMTP connection  
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;         // Connection with the SMTP does require authorization    
    $mail->SMTPSecure = "ssl";      // Connect using a TLS connection  
    $mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";  //Gmail SMTP server address
    $mail->Port = 465;  //Gmail SMTP port
    $mail->Encoding = '7bit';
    
    // Authentication  
    $mail->Username   = "example@gmail.com"; // Your full Gmail address
    $mail->Password   = "examplepassword"; // Your Gmail password
      
    // Compose
    $mail->SetFrom($_POST['emailid'], $_POST['fullname']);
    $mail->AddReplyTo($_POST['emailid'], $_POST['fullname']);
    $mail->Subject = "New Contact Form Enquiry";      // Subject (which isn't required)  
    $mail->MsgHTML($message);
 
    // Send To  
    $mail->AddAddress("examplereceiver@gmail.com", "Mr. Example"); // Where to send it - Recipient
    $result = $mail->Send();  // Send!  
 $message = $result ? '<div class="alert alert-success" role="alert"><strong>Success!</strong>Message Sent Successfully!</div>' : '<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert"><strong>Error!</strong>There was a problem delivering the message.</div>';  

 unset($mail);

}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Contact Form</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">

    <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
  </head>
  <body>
   <div class="contactform">
   <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
     <h3 class="panel-title"><a href="">Contact Form</a></h3>
     </div>
     <div class="panel-body">
     <form name="form1" id="form1" action="" method="post">
       <fieldset>
         <input type="text" class="form-control" name="fullname" placeholder="Volledige Naam" />
         <br />
         <input type="text" class="form-control" name="subject" placeholder="Onderwerp" />
         <br />
         <input type="text" class="form-control" name="phone" placeholder="Telefoonnummer" />
         <br />
         <input type="email" class="form-control" name="emailid" placeholder="Email" />
     <br />
        <div class="checkbox">
          <label>
          <input type="checkbox" name="check_list[]" value="value1">Check me
          </label>
          <label>
          <input type="checkbox" name="check_list[]" value="value2">Check me 2
          </label>
           </div>
         <br />
         <textarea rows="4" class="form-control" cols="20" name="comments" placeholder="Extra tekst indien gewenst"></textarea>
         <br />
         <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success"name="submit" value="Verstuur" />
       </fieldset>
     </form>
     <p><?php if(!empty($message)) echo $message; ?></p>
     </div>
 </div>
 </div>
    <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) 
{

$message=
'Full Name: '.$_POST['fullname'].'<br />
Subject: '.$_POST['subject'].'<br />
Phone: '.$_POST['phone'].'<br />';
foreach($_POST['check_list'] as $check) {
$message .= .$check . '<br>';       
}



Email: '.$_POST['emailid'].'<br />
Comments: '.$_POST['comments'].'
';
    require "PHPMailer-master/class.phpmailer.php"; //include phpmailer class
      
    // Instantiate Class  
    $mail = new PHPMailer();  
      
    // Set up SMTP  
    $mail->IsSMTP();                // Sets up a SMTP connection  
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;         // Connection with the SMTP does require authorization    
    $mail->SMTPSecure = "ssl";      // Connect using a TLS connection  
    $mail->Host = "mail.bjornvdakker.me";  //Gmail SMTP server address
    $mail->Port = 465;  //Gmail SMTP port
    $mail->Encoding = '7bit';
    
    // Authentication  
    $mail->Username   = "support@bjornvdakker.me"; // Your full Gmail address
    $mail->Password   = "5#UPJucxaB7"; // Your Gmail password
      
    // Compose
    $mail->SetFrom($_POST['emailid'], $_POST['fullname']);
    $mail->AddReplyTo($_POST['emailid'], $_POST['fullname']);
    $mail->Subject = "New Contact Form Enquiry";      // Subject (which isn't required)  
    $mail->MsgHTML($message);
 
    // Send To  
    $mail->AddAddress("bjornvdakker@hotmail.com", "Mr. Example"); // Where to send it - Recipient
    $result = $mail->Send();  // Send!  
 $message = $result ? '<div class="alert alert-success" role="alert"><strong>Success!</strong>Message Sent Successfully!</div>' : '<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert"><strong>Error!</strong>There was a problem delivering the message.</div>';  

 unset($mail);

}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Contact Form</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">

    <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
  </head>
  <body>
   <div class="contactform">
   <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
     <h3 class="panel-title"><a href="">Contact Form</a></h3>
     </div>
     <div class="panel-body">
     <form name="form1" id="form1" action="" method="post">
       <fieldset>
         <input type="text" class="form-control" name="fullname" placeholder="Volledige Naam" />
         <br />
         <input type="text" class="form-control" name="subject" placeholder="Onderwerp" />
         <br />
         <input type="text" class="form-control" name="phone" placeholder="Telefoonnummer" />
         <br />
         <input type="email" class="form-control" name="emailid" placeholder="Email" />
     <br />
        <div class="checkbox">
          <label>
          <input type="checkbox" name="check_list[]" value="value1">Check me
          </label>
          <label>
          <input type="checkbox" name="check_list[]" value="value2">Check me 2
          </label>
           </div>
         <br />
         <textarea rows="4" class="form-control" cols="20" name="comments" placeholder="Extra tekst indien gewenst"></textarea>
         <br />
         <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success"name="submit" value="Verstuur" />
       </fieldset>
     </form>
     <p><?php if(!empty($message)) echo $message; ?></p>
     </div>
 </div>
 </div>
    <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

add this to your check boxes:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="check_list[]" value="value1">
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I edited the code and put the new one above at the post, getting an 500 error. I would only like to post the values of the checked boxes in the mail. Is it also possible with this tactic to order the values below eachother? So they don't get placed behind eachother.

Comment: answer updated, your foreach in your code was not placed proper

Comment: Hey keaner, 

I edited the code but still no success. I guess it got something to do with the "layout" of the php code but can't find the error. Got an idea? Posted code above

Comment: still getting a 500 error?. The code works fine for me.

Comment: There was a small syntax error in your code. Fixed it now, thank you really for the support